# Javascript manipulates order form's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, controls

I am currently creating an order form. However, I have been stuck at the value obtaining. It is a product order form, I want to display price and calculate the amount by users' choosing.

For example, I got a product quantity drop down list, so when the user chooses one product, the price div will display one value, if the user chooses 0, the price div will display $0. Where is the problem?

```
var productValue = document.getElementById("e_Product");
var productQuantity = document.getElementById("e_Quantity");
var stringValue = productValue.options[productValue.selectedIndex].text;

if (stringValue == "Product Name" && productQuantity == 1) 
{
    var singleValue = "$800.00";
    $('#e_Price').val(singleValue);
}
else
{
    var singleValue1 = "$0.00";
    $('#e_Price').val(singleValue1);
}
```

When I set two conditions in if statement, the whole function just does not work any more. Also, when I choose the product quantity from 1 to 0, the price field of the form is not updating the number, Do i miss something for the drop down list?

Comment: can you post your html please.

Comment: `productQuantity` is a DOM element, when you're comparing to `1` it's the same as comparing to `true` and in this case seems that it'll always be `true`. Also why mix jQuery and Javascript like that? It looks confusing, you'll end up having to remember whats a jQuery element and what's a native DOM element.

Comment: How can I set a kinda change event into a drop down list which can complete my need? Well, for outputting values in input fields, the jquery way is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use an event handler for updating the field:

```
$("#e_Product").change(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   var quan = $("#e_Quantity").val();
   if (val == "Product Name" && quan == 1)
     var singleValue = "$800.00";
     $('#e_Price').text(singleValue); // if e_Price is a div tag you should use text() instead of val() 
   }
   else
   {
     var singleValue1 = "$0.00";
     $('#e_Price').text(singleValue1);
   }
})
```

Comment: the 'e_Price' is an input field of a form. I have to use val(), that is why I set so many variables... Is it possible to use other function to output the value in input fields? Sounds like it is another question. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Ah, I don't think so, it is a form creator from a cms... The form is generated by xsl. I will keep trying anyway, thank you all the same!!!